# Как правильно подключить ajax к форме с данными в цикле?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Помогите, пожалуйста, корректно подключить ajax к кнопке записи данных в бд.
Есть таблица, в которую в цикле выводятся данные из бд.
Вот код:

```
<table class="table text-center">
 <thead class="text-uppercase">
  <tr>
   <th scope="col">ID</th>
   <th scope="col">Дата</th>
   <th scope="col">Метро</th>
   <th scope="col">Время</th>
   <th scope="col">Номер</th>
   <th scope="col">Фамилия</th>
   <th scope="col">Имя</th>
   <th scope="col">Отчество</th>
   <th scope="col">Сумма</th>
   <th scope="col">Комментарий</th>
   <th scope="col">Курьер</th>
   <th scope="col"> </th>
    <?php $post = get_delivery_users(); ?>
    <?php foreach ($post as $users): ?>
<form method="post" action="courier.php">
<tbody>
<tr>
 <th scope="row"><input type="hidden" name="form_id" value="<?=$users['id']?>"></th>
 <td><div class="form-group">
   <input class="form-control" type="date" name="delivery_date" value="<?=htmlspecialchars($users['delivery_date'], ENT_QUOTES)?>" id="example-date-input"></div></td>
  <td><select name="delivery_adress" class="form-control">
  <? foreach(get_delivery_addresses() as $delivery_address): ?>
  <option <?if ($delivery_address == $users['delivery_adress']) echo ' selected'?>><?=htmlspecialchars($delivery_address, ENT_QUOTES)?></option>
 <? endforeach;?>
 </select></td>

<td><input class="form-control" type="text" name="delivery_time" value="<?=htmlspecialchars($users['delivery_time'], ENT_QUOTES)?>" id="example-text-input"></td>
<td><input class="form-control" type="text" name="phone" value="<?=htmlspecialchars($users['phone'], ENT_QUOTES)?>" id="example-text-input"></td>
<td><input class="form-control" type="text" name="surname" value="<?=htmlspecialchars($users['surname'], ENT_QUOTES)?>"></td>
<td><input class="form-control" type="text" name="name" value="<?=htmlspecialchars($users['name'], ENT_QUOTES)?>"></td>
<td><input class="form-control" type="text" name="second_name" value="<?=htmlspecialchars($users['second_name'], ENT_QUOTES)?>"></td>
<td><input class="form-control" type="text" name="sum" value="<?=htmlspecialchars($users['sum'], ENT_QUOTES)?>"></td>
<td><input class="form-control" type="text" name="manager_comment" value="<?=htmlspecialchars($users['manager_comment'], ENT_QUOTES)?>"></td>
<td><div class="form-group">
<select name="courier" class="form-control">
<? foreach(get_couriers() as $couriers): ?>
<option <?if ($couriers == $users['courier']) echo ' selected'?>><?=htmlspecialchars($couriers, ENT_QUOTES)?></option>
<? endforeach;?>
</select>
</div></td>
<td><button type="submit" formmethod="post" name="couriers" class="btn btn-xs btn-warning mb-3">На доставку</button></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</form>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</table>
```

А вот код, который выполняется в courier.php:

```
    <?php

    require_once('db.php');

    if(isset($_POST['couriers']))
    {
        $form_id = (int)$_POST['form_id'];
        $sum = (int)$_POST['sum'];
        $manager_comment = strip_tags(trim($_POST['manager_comment']));
        $phone = strip_tags(trim($_POST['phone']));
        $name = strip_tags(trim($_POST['name']));
        $surname = strip_tags(trim($_POST['surname']));
        $second_name = strip_tags(trim($_POST['second_name']));
        $manager_comment = strip_tags(trim($_POST['manager_comment']));
        $delivery_adress = strip_tags(trim($_POST['delivery_adress']));
        $delivery_time = strip_tags(trim($_POST['delivery_time']));
        $delivery_date = strip_tags(trim($_POST['delivery_date']));
        $courier = strip_tags(trim($_POST['courier']));
        $SQL = "UPDATE Users SET phone='$phone', sum='$sum', name='$name', surname='$surname', second_name='$second_name', manager_comment='$manager_comment', delivery_adress='$delivery_adress', delivery_time='$delivery_time', delivery_date='$delivery_date', courier='$courier' WHERE id='$form_id'";
        $result = mysqli_query($link, $SQL);

        if ($result) {
            header('Location:delivery.php');
        }
        else {
            printf("Ошибка: %s\n", mysqli_error($link));
        }
    }

?>
```

Как мне сделать корректный ajax запрос к серверу, чтобы запись происходила по нажатию кнопки, но без перезагрузки страницы? Я не до конца понимаю, как это сделать с данными, выведенными в цикле, в т.ч. с записью id.

Answer (score 0):

Короче, пока я ждал, что мне кто-то поможет или объяснит, покопался в примерах и документации...
У меня заработал следующий код (не берусь утверждать, что он идеальный и правильный).

```
$('button[name="couriers"]').on('click', function() {
    let $row = $(this).closest('tr');
    let data = $row.find('input, select').serialize();
    $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "courier.php",
            data: data
        }).done(function() {
            alert("Данные сохранены");
        });
        return false;
    });
```